# sAMAccountName used for logged on users

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, active-directory

When RDP'd to a server I'll often find that there are no available sessions as there are users currently logged in. Within our environment we utilise a user privilege management solution which creates managed domain accounts. For one reason or another the solution will populate the sAMAccountName (pre-Windows 2000 logon name) with a random value similar to the following: *$1LB100-465HL3IJKL4*

It is the sAMAccountName which is displayed when showing the current logged in users instead of the readable User Logon Name.

Is there a way to force Windows to display the UPN instead of the sAMAccountName because as things stand we are unable to tell who is actually logged in and this causes problems when deciding which session to end.

Below is a screenshot that explains my point:
[image]

With the sAMAccountName being displayed instead of the UPN users are unable to easily identify who is logged in and thus who's session can/should be disconnected. Is there a way for Windows to instead display the UPN of the logged in user instead of the sAMAccountName?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: No, I would focus instead on making your privilege management solution stop creating user accounts with mangled names.

Comment: @RyanRies, having read the spec linked below it would appear that the solution is doing exactly as it is supposed to do by creating unique values!

Comment: Are your SAM & UPN's similar? Example, at my shop SAM=xyz123 and UPN=xyz123@mydomain.com. If your UPN is unique & meaningful, ask your vendor how to configure the product to assign the left side of the UPN as the SAM.

Comment: Pretty sure that's the 'default' barring when UPNs are too long. But there's a reason most places adopt an 8 char username policy :)

Answer (score 5):

OK, it's pretty seriously hacky to mess with `sAMAccountName` it's defined in the Windows spec:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms679635%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms677605(v=vs.85).aspx

It exists for compatibility reasons, and I can't honestly think of a good reason to trample it - you can modify your LDAP schema and add custom attributes and fields. But if you've changed something that's *by definition* supposed to be something else, then all sorts of things are just going to break in various ways.

You wouldn't want to use UPN, because that's defined by the Kerberos spec, and can actually be quite long - and thus not much use for an on screen display.

What you really want is a unique, per account value, that's short. Which is what `sAMAccountName` is defined as. If you can't get your security management software to use something else, I'd be suggesting that you *SERIOUSLY* consider throwing it out and getting one that doesn't suck*.

* I appreciate this is straying into the realm of 'opinion', but I would justify it by point out that as a professional sysadmin - this is *exactly* the sort of thing that makes systems unreliable, unpredictable and unstable, and that you should Just Never Do.

Comment: I'm not looking to go against any of the specifications. I don't think I explained my question very well... I'll edit now.

Comment: This field is supposed to be: "the logon name" - with some additional restrictions for backwards compatibility. The fact you're using it for something else (e.g. your account management software) is what I meant by going against specifications. Otherwise, as far as your server is concerned... it's displaying a list of accounts logged in to the box.

Comment: I'm not using it for the account management software. The software creates domain accounts and populates the sAMAccountName with a unique (rightly so) value which can be seen in my screenshot. I know what the server is showing, what I'm asking is if it's possible for the server to instead show the value that is stored in the User Logon Name as opposed to the value of the sAMAccountName.

Comment: I'm 95% sure the answer to that is no, you can't. Your account names are tied into such a lot of things at a low level. Process lists, file ownerships etc. I think it's the only entry in the standard LDAP schema that holds a standalone/globally unique 'account name'.